# Minimize WebPart is hidden SharePoint 2013

Tags: web-part

In SharePoint 2007/2010 you always had the little arrow on the right side of WebParts which could **minimize** WebParts or **edit** them.

SharePoint 2013 does away with these and doesn't render the ControlBox for WebParts. It *does render it in edit mode* of the page

[image].

I have customers using this feature to hide and display WebParts - is it possible to also render the controlbox (I call it that because the CSS is `ms-webpart-controlBox`) in display mode of the page?

Answer (score 1):

It does not happen only in 2013, in 2007, some users have some of these control boxes showing in some web-parts, not in others.  One user gets different results based on page refresh or page load, or reload, others consistently see nothing rendered.  At the designer's workstation (i.e., his PC), they show up as expected, on every web-part that allows minimize. Hideous inconsistency no matter what the reason.